# All possible moves

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, move, doubly-linked-list

I have this problem to solve and I need a little bit of help.

So we have this train with wagons. Each wagon has a value for **volume**, which mustn't be exceeded by the sum value of the cargoes in  wagon **at all time**. Each cargo also has a value for **volume**. Wagons are linked in Doubly Linked List and so are the cargoes in each wagon. The task is to move cargoes from wagon to wagon so that in the end we have the least amount of filled wagons.

condition: You can only move a cargo to the wagon on the right or to the left.

Can this problem be linked to any known programming algorithm, because I really don't want a solution using permutations and going through all possible moves?

The task starts with you receiving an unknown train. The first step would be that you go trough Doubly Linked List of wagons so that you know the number of wagons and in each wagon you should go trough Doubly Linked List of cargoes so that you know whit what composition you're dealing with.

Comment: That's vaguely the [Knapsack Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), which is very complex to compute. I'm not clear the data structures are relevant: you've just got a set of objects to put into a set of containers? Is there any more complexity than that?

Comment: We can move cargo to any wagon? or just to connected?

Comment: @Rup The actual problem is linked from that page: [Bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). As described, it's an NP-hard problem.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, you can only move a cargo to the wagon on the left or to the one on the right

Comment: OK, which means you might get into tower-of-hanoi like situations where you need to move stuff out of the way so you can make one multiple-wagon move, but that's slightly orthogonal to working out the best final position I think?

Comment: @Phylogenesis Neat, thanks! I hadn't heard of that.

Comment: as those problems mentioned are quite complex, you might want to check meta heuristics. I've implemented a similar solution - just that it was with racks, servers and VMs and how to allocate VMs across servers / racks - using simulated annealing and the results were pretty good, given the time i needed for the implementation and for calculating a result

Comment: Is it even NP-complete? How do you know you checked enough combinations  to prove that none of the remaining can be a better solution? NP-complete problems usually have finite number of possible solutions, but here, you can just move the same cargo left and right endless times. This can be more complex from the Bin packing problem, in which you can just add a cargo to any wagon from nowhere. Here, you can only put cargo from wagons next to each other.

Comment: @Attila That's easy enough to prevent though: just require that you never return to a previous overall position during your search. And there are finitely many positions of cargo within the wagons, and finite ways to get there without self-repetition.

Comment: Ah, the wagons count is given, ok.

Comment: Actually he doesn't specify that, true, but I can't see why you'd ever need more wagons than you have individual pieces of cargo which would make a reasonable upper bound to consider.

Comment: Where do the cargo items start?  Also it's interesting to note that there can be "bottlenecks" in the wagons that prevent certain cargo items from getting through even if they would fit on the other side, no matter how hard you Tower-of-Hanoi things.

Comment: I added start of the task

Comment: To me it seems much harder than bin packing. If wagon volume is 10 and you have an initial configuration of 3 wagons, 1 cargo per wagon, volumes of the cargoes being 5 6 5, then you are stuck to 3 wagons (the bottle necks @j_random_hacker was talking about). Every bin packing approx algorithm (FFD, MFFD, ...) would trivially give you 2 wagons